Livewire form validation and submission
in my learning journey to laravel livewire , i've face some difficulties.. here I'm validating a simple form , when i click submit button , it is quickly submit the form without a little delays , how can i delay form submission for a few seconds before displaying success or error message?
    {{-- bind success message --}}
<div>
    @if(session()->has('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success" id="success-message">
            {{ session('success') }}
        </div>
    @endif

    {{-- form starts --}}
    <form wire:submit.prevent="submitForm">
        <div class="card shadow">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="card-title fw-bold">Livewire Form Validation </h4>
            </div>                    
            <div class="card-body">                        
                {{-- name --}}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" wire:model="name" placeholder="Name" aria-describedby="name-error" aria-required="true" @error('name') aria-invalid="true" @enderror class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror">                            
                    {{-- Display name validation error message --}}
                    @error('name')
                        <span id="name-error" class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                    @enderror
                </div>                        
                {{-- email --}}
                <div class="form-group my-3">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" id="email" wire:model="email" placeholder="Email" aria-describedby="email-error" @error('email') aria-invalid="true" @enderror class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror">                            
                    {{-- Display email validation error message --}}
                    @error('email')
                        <span id="email-error" class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
                    @enderror
                </div>                       
                <div class="form-group mb-2">
    <button type="button" wire:click.delay="submit">submit</button>
 
<!---load spinner-->
<div wire:loading>
        <svg>...</svg> 
    </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    {{-- form ends --}}
</div>

    <?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use App\Models\Subscription;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class SubscriptionForm extends Component
{
    public $name, $email;

    public function submitForm()
    { 
        $validateFields = $this->validate([
            'email' => [
                'required',
                'email',
                Rule::unique('subscriptions')->ignore($this->email),
            ],
            'name' => 'required|min:5',
        ], [
            'email.unique' => 'This email has already been used.',
        ]);

        Subscription::create($validateFields);
        $this->reset(); 
        session()->flash('success', 'Successfully subscribed.');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.subscription-form');
    }
}

from the official docs the loading spinner indicator is simple as
<div wire:loading>
    <svg>...</svg> <!-- SVG loading spinner -->
</div>

but when i implementing it to my blade view it does not work at all
how can i achieve those logic? showing loading indicator when submitting the form and delaying responses before showing validation messages?

You can use the sleep() function on the backend side to delay the response, e.g.:
public function submitForm()
{
   sleep(2); // waits 2 seconds

   $validateFields = $this->validate([.....

   .....
}


It's logical to show validation error after form submission and for a few seconds then submit form so your codes should be like this:
Component
 <?php
    
    namespace App\Livewire;
    
    use Livewire\Component;
    use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
    use App\Models\Subscription;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
    
    class SubscriptionForm extends Component
    {
        public $name, $email;
    
        public function submitForm()
        { 
            $validateFields = $this->validate([
                'email' => [
                    'required',
                    'email',
                    Rule::unique('subscriptions')->ignore($this->email),
                ],
                'name' => 'required|min:5',
            ], [
                'email.unique' => 'This email has already been used.',
            ]);
    
            sleep(2); // added this line

            Subscription::create($validateFields);
            $this->reset(); 
            session()->flash('success', 'Successfully subscribed.');
        }
    
        public function render()
        {
            return view('livewire.subscription-form');
        }
    }


The asker has said "before showing validation messages"

@Pippo can u modify one of the given solutions? to solve the problem

The solutions can both be valid: with mine the delay is applied even when the validation fails and error messages are shown, with @Mehdi's solution the delay is applied only after validation, therefore in case of errors there is no delay. I believe I have proposed a solution that reflects your request, however it is up to you to decide which one you prefer, you can also try both
